# MySQLi INSERT not working

Tags: php, mysql

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
while(true){
    // Check how many API calls remain
    $rate_limit = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.twitter.com/1/account/rate_limit_status.json'),true);
    // Array containing all the Twitter handles
    $handles = array('le4ky');

    if($rate_limit['remaining_hits']<count($handles)){
        file_put_contents('tweet_gremlin.log', date('r') . ' Rate limit reached');
        sleep(30);
    }else{
        // Establish the database connection
        if(!$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost','twitterd','password','twitterd')){
            die('Cannot connect to database');
            file_put_contents('tweet_gremlin.log', date('r') . ' Cannot connect to the database');
        }


        // This is the big one.  Loop through the $handles values, make an API call, and insert the tweets.
        foreach($handles as $value){
            // Get the handle's timeline and put it into $user_data
            $user_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=from:' . $value . '&rpp=100'),true);
            // Put only the results index (tweets) into into $user_data
            $user_data = $user_data['results'];

            for($i=0;$i<count($user_data);$i++){

                // Lazy method for sanitizing variables
                $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$user_data[$i]['id']);
                $created_at = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$user_data[$i]['created_at']);
                $from_user_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$user_data[$i]['from_user_id']);
                $profile_image_url = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$user_data[$i]['profile_image_url']);
                $from_user = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$user_data[$i]['from_user']);
                $from_user_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$user_data[$i]['from_user_name']);
                $text = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$user_data[$i]['text']);

                $insert_tweets = "INSERT INTO tweets ('id','created_at','from_user_id','profile_image','from_user','from_user_name',`text`) VALUES ({$id},{$created_at},{$from_user_id},{$profile_image_url},{$from_user},{$from_user_name},{$text});";
                $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$insert_tweets);
            }
        }
        sleep(30);
    }
}
?>
```

This is basically just meant to be a "daemon" of sorts that retrieves data and inserts it into the database.  For the life of me, I can't figure out why the data isn't being inserted into the database.  The twitterd user has select and insert permissions on the database and can connect from any host.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need quotes around string values in your SQL query:

```
$insert_tweets = "
    INSERT INTO tweets
        (`id`,`created_at`,`from_user_id`,`profile_image`,`from_user`,`from_user_name`,`text`) 
    VALUES  
        ('{$id}','{$created_at}','{$from_user_id}','{$profile_image_url}','{$from_user}','{$from_user_name}','{$text}')
";
```

I added them to all values, you can remove them on values you know are numeric (and validated with `intval()`, `floatval()` or some other numeric validation function).

I also replaced single quotes with backticks in your column names.

Comment: So another question...  Do you see anything wrong with the for() loop that loops through $handles?  I added two more users to the array and the script isn't grabbing data for them.  Only the first user in the array.

Comment: Hmmm, nevermind.  I removed the $result variable and now it works fine.  Any thoughts on why that happened?

Comment: If all you did was remove `$result`, that's strange, as it shouldn't matter if that's present or not (since you're not using `$result` down the road).